# C# / WPF - Changing the Cursor global

Tags: c#, wpf, input, cursor, global

if I set the Cursor in my Wpf app like this:

`this.Cursor = System.Windows.Input.Cursors.Hand;`

it only effects the Wpf app, but  I want to do this change Windows global - any ideas?

Comment: I tried, but didn't find anything. Help me or let it be.

Comment: No, you don't want that. Why terrorize the entire machine because of something going on in your app? There's a lot more going on in a multi-tasking OS, most of it happily oblivious of anything occurring in your wonderful app. And then, I think most applications would overrule your cursor by their own cursor handling.

Answer (score 1):

It is a registry call and an API call to reload.

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/csharpgeneral/thread/977e2f40-3222-4e13-90ea-4e8d0cdf289c/